# What happens when you are missing an 8086 missing jump operand?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-16

I'm working on updating some old 8086 assembly code to a more modern system. In my reverse engineering I came across this:

```
LINADJ: MOV AX,ENRMAX
SUB AX,LINBND       ;Is energy high enough to decrease power limit?
JLE ENDCYC          ;If not, don't change power limit
```

The problem is that there is no `ENDCYC` tag to jump to in this file. What happens when a Jump command doesn't have a valid label to jump to?

Excuse my novice assembly skills, but this label shows up in other closely related files but from what I understand you can't jump from one file to another. So I'm assuming that this jump either becomes a no-op or throws some kind of error.

Comment: You can of course jump into another file. It's the job of the linker to update the address. Depending on your assembler you might have to declare the target label as `extern` or similar in the calling module and as `global` in the exporting one. If there is a problem you will get an error from the assembler or the linker. It will never become a no-op (unless your toolchain is brain dead).

Comment: What should I look for to tell if it is jumping out of this file? It seems like most of the external references in this code are called or included. `$INCLUDE(:@ARCS:MEMSLV.A86)` or `CALL AUDIT`

Comment: `CALL` or `JLE` makes no difference to label visibility. If it's not in the current file and the code is known to work, then it's going to another file. Look for the `global` and `extern` directives or whatever is equivalent in your assembler.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly this could be jumping to an ENDCYC label in another file? It would seem to me that you would need to tell it which file had the ENDCYC label.

Comment: You don't need to specify the file. There should be only one globally visible `ENDCYC` label in the object files you link together. The linker will find it. You do need to pass the appropriate **object** files (and libraries) to the linker obviously.

Comment: Hmm. I'm probably going to sound dumb (8086 is well before my time). But from what I can tell, the other piece of code that contains the `ENDCYC` label is designed to run on another processor completely. These two processors share memory space to communicate back and forth.  It seems very unlikely that these two files would be linked even though they communicate with each other.

Comment: We can't tell more from the information you provided. Code may be shared between processors though.

Comment: Sadly I doubt I'm allowed to post the entire code. It had to go through export control to get to me. Government work... If we assumed that it wasn't shared and was just missing the label would this still compile/run?

Comment: no, in almost all likelihood it wouldn't be able to assemble/link with a label that isn't defined. in fact just rename ENDCYC to ENDCYC1234 or some other label that is known not to exist anywhere and see what happens to the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above. It seems that the final solution is that ENDCYC existed in another piece of code that was linked to the code that I was reverse engineering. After finishing the code under the ENDCYC label it jumps back to the original piece of code. So to answer my own question, yes you can jump from one piece of code to another if they are linked together.